# A problem about the improper integral in Jensen's formula

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

In [Jensen's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_formula), when dealing with zeros of $f$ in the boundary of $D(0;r)$, we need the following lemma:
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\log\left(\left\vert\,1 - {\rm e}^{{\rm i}t}\,\right\vert\right)\,{\rm d}t = 0.
$$

My question is how much one could understand this improper integral (e.g. Is it Lebesgue integrable?) As far as I know, apply Cauchy's theorem, we have its [Cauchy principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value):
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} \int_{\epsilon}^{2\pi - \epsilon}\log\left(\left\vert\,1 - {\rm e}^{{\rm i}t}\,\right\vert\right)\,{\rm d}t = 0.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The singularity is of the form $\int_{-1}^1 \log|x| \, dx$.  This is a very mild singularity in that $\int_{\epsilon}^1 |\log|x|| \, dx = \epsilon \log \epsilon - \epsilon + 1 $ converges as $\epsilon \to 0^+$.  In particular, it is definitely Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: So $\log |x|$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[-1,1]$. Could you mind elaborate for me how I can change variable to get the integral in my question?

Comment: $\log|1-e^{it}| = \log|t| + \log|(1-e^{it})/t|$.  Since $(1-e^{it})/t$ converges as $t \to 0$, the singularity of $\log|1-e^{it}|$ and $\log|t|$ are of the same nature at $t=0$.

Comment: Agree. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Since $1-e^{it}=(1-\cos t)-i\sin t$, $\sin^2t+\cos^2t=1$ and $1-\cos t=2\sin^2 \dfrac t2$ you want to prove that $$\int_0^{2\pi}\log \sqrt{2(1-\cos t)}dt=\int_0^{2\pi}\log {2\sin\frac t 2}dt=0$$

that is $$\frac 1 2\int_0^{2\pi}\log\sin\frac t 2dt=\int_0^\pi\log\sin tdt=-\pi\log 2$$

This is actually a known integral, and has been answered a few times here in MSE.

**ADD** The function is Lebesgue integrable, since $−\log\sin t$ is positive over [0,π/2] and bounded above by $−\log(2t/π)$ which is cleary Lebesgue integrable over $[0,π/2]$. You can use monotone convergence, and symmetry about $\pi/2$.

Comment: Here, again I wonder if $\int_{0}^{\pi}\log(\sin t)\,dt$ is Lebesgue integrable? or it is just Cauchy principle value?

Comment: Yes, the function is Lebesgue integrable. $-\log\sin t$ is positive over $[0,\pi]$ and bounded above by $-\log\left(\dfrac{2x}{\pi}\right)$ which is cleary Lebesgue integrable over $[0,\pi]$. You can use monotone convergence.

Comment: I don't figure out how to get that bounded, what is $x$?

Comment: @DuPhan Sorry, $x$ is just another dummy variable. I should have said "over $[0,\pi/2]$", also. Note $\log\sin x$ is symmetric w.r.t. $x=\pi/2$.

Comment: I know $\sin x \leq x$, but this is the first time I see $\sin x \geq \frac{2x}{\pi}$ :) Thanks.